# After moving CI from one provider to another I get white screen of death on my homepage

Tags: codeigniter

**I have moved my CodeIgniter application from my first server provider where everything works great to another one ( because of better speed etc.) and I have now two strange problems with WSOD.**

**When I go to my homepage I get a WSOD.**

Well, I tried to remve the index.html file in the root and it magically works.

My question is **why I need to remove the index.html file if it is there as a default file in CI package?**

**Is this a problem of the server?** What should they change so I can leave index.html in my root? **Should they enable some module or?**

I think it is better for security reason to have index.html in the root folder or am I wrong?

My another problem is that when there is a redirect, e.g. on login, submiting form. I get after hitting submit a WSOD. But only when the validation is successful, so I am asssuming that the redirect failed.

**One thing to notice. I am not using refresh as the second parameter, bacause it causes problems WSOD on my localhost.**

Could this be a problem?

Which Apache or PHP server configuration paramter could cause this problem?

**EDIT: I tried redirect('admin', 'refresh'); and also redirect('admin', 'location', 301); but I am still getting WSOD :(.**

**EDIT 2: Could this be an issue of disabled FastCGI PHP5?**

**EDIT 3: My base url in config file is OK: $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.myproblematicpage.com/'; . It has the trailing slash and everything what is needed. I am not using subfolders etc.**

**EDIT 4: I have changed the title of this post to be clear that everything works on my first provider, but this problem emerges after moving to another**

Comment: change your base url to meet the requirement

Comment: It is OK, this has to do something with the server configuration or htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after enabling showing errors in index.php (changing production to development mode) I saw that the problem was on the first line of the **form_validation_lang.php** file in my application/language/english folder. But I didn't saw any whitespaces before the first UTF-8 without BOM and BANG!... the problem disappeared. Probably the BOM was the troublemaker. However, I still don't know how could it work on the previous hosting.

Comment: Maybe it was a config issue, and this new server was showing index.html before index.php, preventing any business logic from taking place.